# How to force a subclass to implement the method of its non-abstract, non-interface-implemented parent class in java?

Tags: java

These days when I read the doc of "[handleMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message))", I find its description that "**Subclasses must implement this** to receive messages." (Some other examples are the "[Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/Loader#protected-methods)" class, where the "onAbandon", "onCancelLoad" methods, etc. also have the same descriptions)

I am so confused because the "handleMessage" is a public method of "Handler" class (and "Handler" class is the direct class of Object class), **but neither the "Handler" class is abstract, nor the "Handler" class implement any interface. Also, "handleMessage" itself is not an abstract method.** How can java guarantee users to "must implement this (via subclasses)" ?

Comment: You misunderstand the docs.  "Subclasses must implement this to receive messages" means that they're free not to implement it, but if they don't then they won't receive messages.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans Oh I see! What a stup*d question I have asked LOL...... Thank you!